# Selenium webdriver tests pass indivdually but fail when run together

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I have a java file which has 7 junit tests to run. If I run all the tests at once all but 1 passes. If I comment out certain tests and that one test always passes.

Can anybody offer any suggestions as to what could be causing this?

My first thought was something in the test Setup or cleanup but I am not sure what it could be. All I do in the clean up is exit the driver and output the time taken to run the test.

In the setup I set up the driver, the time started, create a firefox profile and read in some data from a properties file to use in the tests.

If it was the setup / cleanup surely the other 6 tests would also be effected? The test that fails is a simple test to check that entering an invalid card type displays an error message on the page.

UPDATE:
I've renamed the test so it runs first and now all 7 pass each time. What could be causing this? Do I need to set something in my test cleanup to get it back to a default state?

My test cleanup:

```
@After
public void testCleanup() throws IOException {

    driver.quit();
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = ((endTime - startTime)/1000)/60;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Test Suite Took: " + totalTime + " Minutes.");
}
```

Comment: Can you post your java code?

Comment: There's a lot of it and it calls other files. Is there a specific part I can post?

Comment: WebDriver tests are often sensitive to timing issues - mosty on pages with elements loaded by AJAX. Are you sure your [implicit and explicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) are ok? Try to pinpoint the problem, try what you can delete to make the tests still behave in the same fashion. Does test order have any effect? And yeah, without any code and/or reproducible testcase, we can only guess.

Comment: It may also be helpful if you could post the actual error message of the test that failed.

Comment: Sorry it's not actually failing it's the assert which return the wrong result when run with the other tests. I am going to change the test name now so it runs first to see if the test order is causing it.

Comment: Ok making that test run first in the group and they all passed. What could be causing that? Do I need to do something extra in my cleanup?

Comment: Your tests should not rely on an order for them to pass. Each should 'stand alone'. From what you've explained it sounds like one of your tests places your system into a state that is saved between sessions. As such when you reach the test that was failing, it was expecting something but due to the previous test, that something is something-else. If you want to ensure that your tests are 'clean', remember to 'unset' whatever you set during your test - even do this at the end of the test-method if you need to rather than via the @After method

Comment: Show us your Test Class.. most likely will shed some light.